# Not able to store file locally on EC2 before attaching it to email - Camel

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, apache-camel

I am generating a csv file, and trying to send it as an attachment to the email. My code looks something like this:

```
    .to("file://reports/out?fileName=${property.Report}-${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmm}.csv&autoCreate=true")
    .bean(MyMailer.class)
    .to("smtp://mysmarthost.myorg.com:25")
```

The MyMailer bean, fetches this file and attaches it to the email.

```
Message in = exchange.getIn();
Map headers = in.getHeaders();

String fileName = (String )headers.get("CamelFileNameProduced");
fileName = StringUtils.substringAfterLast(fileName, File.separator);

in.addAttachment(fileName,
            new DataHandler(new FileDataSource((String )headers.get("CamelFileNameProduced"))));
```

I am able to receive an email on my local machine. But, when I deploy my applicaiton to EC2 instance, I get the following exception. I have tried providing full access rights but the problem still persists. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.

StackTrace

```
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot store file: reports/out/My_Data-201704171500.csv
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:344)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.writeFile(GenericFileProducer.java:277)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.processExchange(GenericFileProducer.java:165)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.process(GenericFileProducer.java:79)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:117)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:117)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:117)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.loadbalancer.QueueLoadBalancer.process(QueueLoadBalancer.java:44)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerSupport.process(LoadBalancerSupport.java:97)
    at org.apache.camel.component.quartz.QuartzEndpoint.onJobExecute(QuartzEndpoint.java:144)
    at org.apache.camel.component.quartz.CamelJob.execute(CamelJob.java:63)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:223)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: reports/out/My_Data-201704171500.csv (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.prepareOutputFileChannel(FileOperations.java:505)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.writeFileByStream(FileOperations.java:444)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:326)
    ... 60 more
```

Comment: The error indicates a failure to write to a relative file path.  So you'll need to know what the working directory of your Java process is to determine the location it's actually attempting to write to.

Comment: If you run on EC2 then you may need to have some persistent file store attached so you can store files. The local file system is likely locked down what you can access/store etc. Study EC2 and how that works